# Close and Open another Jquery Popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have 2 popups on 2 different pages. The homepage link displays the first popup. And the Popup page button displays the second popup by first closing the 1st popup. The second popup configuration is there with first popup. When I try to accomplish the above, I am unable to close the 1st popup and display the 2nd.

Any suggestions how I might get this to work correctly?

**Code**

```
$(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("dialog")
        .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
        .attr("overflow", "hidden")
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
            width: 1000,
            title: $(this).attr("dialog-title"),
            close: function () { $(this).remove() },
            modal: true,
            position: "top"
        }).load(this.href);
    });
    $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
    });
```

**Button Code**

```
<input id="submit1" type="submit" class="styled-button" value="Make Copy" name="sub" />
```

**Jquery Event to close and open popup**

```
$("#submit1").click(function () {
    $(".dialog").dialog("close");
    $(this).addClass('openDialog');
    window.setTimeout(function () { $(this).trigger('click') }, 200);
});
```

Comment: try with live , that is $("#submit1").live('click' , function () {...

Comment: stop using `live` people! it doesn't exist anymore from jquery-1.9.x!

Comment: Tried. No more helpful.

Comment: I tried creating a jsfiddle of this, so problem 1 is: your dialog is modal, thus not being able to click the other(submit1) button.  if you can please create a proper js fiddle, itll help us a lot.  Also as @scarecrow has mentioned, stop using live, and us on.